# How do I cancel a git stash pop while keeping the original local changes?

Tags: git

I have some local changes and want to `git stash` it, but I instead executed `git stash pop` by mistake. (By tortoise GUI) I even don't know what I popped.

Can I cancel the `stash pop` and still keep the original local changes?

Comment: Your situation is doubly bad because a) the unsaved local changes have been overwritten by the stash, and b) you did a `stash pop`, which means that the stash itself is no longer in the stash stack.  So, you lost your work and you may have lost the stash.  One option here might be to use local history of your IDE or development environment, to get back the changes before the stash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71079884/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+stash+pop